# MySQL - using MAX and a subquery together?

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Thanks in advance for any help!

```
TABLES

domains: (id,domain_name)
1   bing.com
2   google.com
3   bongo.com

dns_checks (id, domain_id, check_date)
1   1   2020/1/1
2   1   2020/2/3
3   2   2020/1/1
4   2   2020/2/3
5   2   2020/2/3

dns_records (id, dns_check_id, domain_id, value)

1    4    2    mx.google.com
2    4    2    www.google.com
3    4    2    google.com
4    2    1    www.bing.com
5    5    2    www.google.com
```

I'm trying to list my domain names along with the LATEST copy of DNS records in the most recent'check' done so the desired output based on the data above would be something like:

```
DOMAIN        NO of DNS RECORDS
google.com      1*
bing.com        1

*(because I only want the count for the records in the LATEST dns_check for each domain)
```

At the moment I can only work out how to count ALL records across every historic 'check':

```
SELECT id,domain_name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dns_records WHERE dns_records.domain_id=domains.id) AS total_records FROM `domains`
```

What I'm trying to do is something like:

```
SELECT id,domain_name, (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dns_records INNER JOIN dns_checks ON dns_records.dns_check_id=MAX(dns_checks.id) WHERE dns_checks.domain_id=domains.id) AS latest_dns_records FROM `domains`
```

I've tried loads of variations but just can't seem to nail the syntax (doesn't help that I don't know if its possible!).

Comment: @Strawberry, thanks for the pointer and a good shout - I've added sample data now which I hope makes it clearer

Comment: I refer you again to my previous comment

Comment: And I, in turn ,draw your attention to my thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below query:

```
with latestCheckedDomains as (
select Rank()over(partition by d.id order by dr.dns_check_id desc) rownumber,domain_name from domains d, dns_checks dc,dns_records dr 
where d.id=dc.domain_id and dc.id=dr.dns_check_id and dc.domain_id=dr.domain_id
)
select domain_name Domain,count(*) NOofDNSRECORDS from latestCheckedDomains
where rownumber=1
group by domain_name
```

Comment: Thanks @Kazi, I've tried this and am getting a count for ALL records, not just the latest 'check'

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. I have changed my answer. Please chck.

Comment: No need to apologise - you are helping me!  :-)  I've tried pasting the above but I'm not sure what I'm supposed to put where you have "[NO of DNS RECORDS]".  I also do't know what you mean in your question or the when you talk about "[![enter code here][1]][1]"? 

If it helps, what I am trying to get is a list ALL domains and to count the number of dns_records linked to the LATEST dns_check for each domain name.

Comment: I have made t he changes. Please try now. I don't have mysql in my pc. Otherwise I will check it there. It's working in sql server.

Comment: thanks for your help - that has worked a treat!

Answer (score 0):

You can use `join` and `not exists` as follows:

```
SELECT d.id, d.domain_name, count(*) as cnt
FROM `domains` d
Left join dns_checks c on c.domain_id=d.id
Left join dns_records r on r.dns_check_id = c.id
Where not exists 
      (Select 1 from dns_check cc
        Where c.domain_id=d.id and cc.id > c.id)
```

Comment: Thanks @Popeye, I tried this and it does have the DNS record count correct (latest check onlt) but it is only showing one row (the count for one domain)